# Avoiding the use of template literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm doing some plots with d3, and I'm actually parsing my javascript code from another programming language. Now, I'm facing some issues when I need to parse the "dollar sign", so I'm trying to avoid it. Now, I'm not very used to Javascript, and as I was coding my graph in `d3`, I saw the following implementation:

```
function zoomed({transform}) {
    myimage.attr("transform", d => `translate(\${transform.apply(d)})`);
  }
```

Now, what I'd like to know is if there is a "direct" way of coding this in such a way as to avoid the whole `translate(\${transform.apply(d)})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the `$` from the template literal by switching to string concatenation:

```js
myimage.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + transform.apply(d) + ")")
```